# mod_rewrite - Allow external access to a single URL pattern

Tags: php, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2

We have a symfony2 app (not that I suspect that matters), but we want to allow external access to URLs of a certain pattern from everywhere, but block all access from outside our 10.x IP network.

Ideally, we would block by IP, it would be simple, but the servers that need remote access can be a variety of IPs, so its not so simple.

The path is /app.php/dir1/dir2/file - this is what needs to be globally accessible (obviously altered for use here, but its that structure).

I'm presuming this is mod_rewrite rather than anything else, but any solutions are welcome.

Comment: You should chose another approach: to implement some minimal local proxy that is accessible from "the outside". That way you do not have to meddle with the internal logic of your app which always means great risk of getting broken during upgrades or changes. So try to keep separate things separate. That minimal proxy could be implemented using apaches mod_proxy from within the rewriting module, but as said: keep it separate, maybe in a separate host or even a separate system accessible from "the outside". you also gain the advantage that you can freely chose the URL pattern visible outside.

Comment: Yeah, that was another idea we were mulling over.

Comment: It allows you to limit access to that proxy host for IPs and ranges of such without having to consider paths or urls at that point. much easier to implement and maintain. And the overhead should be minimal, just define a host inside your apache, limit access and implement rewriting rules with a proxy flag (`P`) for those urls you want to be accessible.